# Why won't my HTML file run/import my JS file?

Tags: web3js, javascript

My `app.js` file runs a `node.js` HTML server using `nodemon app.js`. I'm using `fs.readFile` to run `index.html` for the front-end. `index.html` file imports `main.js` using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/lennard/Desktop/numberChanger/build/app/main.js"></script>`.
But when I start up the server and run the app in Chrome, `index.html` apparently does not find `main.js` as I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I suspect that `index.html` is somehow loading itself whilst looking for `main.js`. When looking at Chrome's JS console the `main.js` file seems to be showing the contents of `index.html`:

[image]

When I simply copy and paste the `main.js` contents within the `index.html` `<script>` tags the code seems to execute just fine.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Browser limit interaction between a html page and local filesystem. You should launch your page from a http server like https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server.